# Looping with the HTML code

Tags: html

Is it possible to implement the For loop or while Loop technique with the use of HTML tags?

OR any tags which helps us to give this feature in plain HTML pages?

Comment: AFAIK, HTML is a data display or markup language

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, it is a markup language! if you mean no server script by plain html you could use javascript.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language, so it won't be able to loop for you. What is it that you're trying to do? Perhaps we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

You can't implement any looping with plain HTML, you'd need to implement it in something else like Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML contains no such logic. Java Script would be your best shot if no server-technology available.

regards,
//t